# Restlet client returns null

Tags: java, jax-rs, restlet

I have an jax-rs annotated interface

```
public interface Store {

    @Path("/apipath")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Token login(@BeanParam Header header, 
        @FormParam(value = "type") String type);        

}
```

Token is a class annotated with jaxb annotations.

I want to use this interface as a client proxy.

```
Store s = new ClientResource(url).wrap(Store.class);
Token t = s.login(...);
```

The returned token is always null. No exception is thrown. If i use the same interface but as a jax-rs implementation i choose either cxf or resteasy the method returns non-null object with correct data.

im using org.restlet.ext.jaxrs 2.3.3, org.restlet.ext.jackson 2.3.3, org.restlet.ext.jaxb 2.3.1

Comment: Hello. Could add the content of the `Token` in your question? So I could try to reproduce your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @thierrytemplier This seems like a bug in restlet. I changed my code for a bit. `JaxRsClientResource resource = new JaxRsClientResource(context, new Reference(apiUrl));
        store = resource.wrap(Store.class);` Now it returns 409 - In the header class is a field annotated with `@headerparams` which is not being send in the request.

Comment: It's a bit strange for the 409 error. I don't think that it's something thrown by Restlet. Do you where it's thrown? Regarding the header class, I'm not sure to understand what you mean. By header class, you think of the `org.restlet.data.header` one? What do you mean by your last sentence? Would it be possible to update your question to give us more details about what you tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientResource` class and its `wrap` method only supports native Restlet annotations (like `@Get`, `@Post`, ...). The `JaxRsClientResource` does something similar but in the context of JAX-RS.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry